# FormBuilder helper method with block capture not working in ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a custom FormBuilder that has a group method that acts as a wrapper around each label/input/hint/error combo. The group method itself is very simple, but when I try to use it from ERB like I would with "fields_for" or similar, it does not render properly.

```rb
def group(**options, &)
  options[:class] = class_names(options[:class] || "flex flex-col mt-4", options.delete(:classes))
  
  content_tag(:div, capture(&), **options)
end
```

In the ViewComponent that is using the form helper I can do the following just fine

```rb
def call
  @form.group(**@group) do
    concat @form.label(:tags, @label.delete(:text), **@label)
    concat @form.text_field(:tags, **@system_arguments)
  end
end
```

But if I try to write that in an ERB partial, it either does not render the wrapper from group at all, or it only renders the text_field and not the label

```rb
<%= @form.group(**@group) do %>
  <%= @form.label(:tags, @label.delete(:text), **@label) %>
  <%= @form.text_field(:tags, **@system_arguments) %>
<% end %>
```

Not sure what I'm missing to get the ERB version to work properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fix, but it's not released yet:
*https://github.com/ViewComponent/view_component/pull/1650*

```rb
# Gemfile
gem "view_component", github: "ViewComponent/view_component"
```

```rb
# config/application.rb
config.view_component.capture_compatibility_patch_enabled = true
```

---

*https://viewcomponent.org/known_issues.html#compatibility-with-rails-form-helpers*

Comment: I might be missing somethere here but why is the ViewComponent gem relevant to the question? I can't see anything in the answer that implies that its in use and its not a dependency of any Rails version I know of.

Comment: He read between the lines a bit. Both render options are ViewComponent `call` vs `template` paths.

Comment: @max it did say `component` in the question + form render issue, made me think ViewComponent.